# Extjs grid limit column show/hide checks

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to limit user from checking/unchecking columns in grid. It is a default `extjs` grid and I want something like, on `beforeselect` event or config to be applied on columns menu `checkboxes`. so if max allowed columns are selected and user tries to check more columns, the error message should pop up.

Please guide me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that error message stuff, because error messages are annoying the user. I would disable unchecked columns in the `columnshow` event when the maximum is reached, like this:

```
  var doCheckItems = function() {
          var showncolumns = Ext.Array.sum(grid.headerCt.query("gridcolumn").map(function(column) {return column.isVisible()?1:0;}));
          if(showncolumns >= 5) {
              Ext.each(grid.headerCt.getMenu().query("menucheckitem"),function(item) {
                  if(!item.checked) item.disable();
              })
          } else {
              Ext.each(grid.headerCt.getMenu().query("menucheckitem"),function(item) {
                  item.enable();
              })
          }
      };

  grid.headerCt.on('columnshow',doCheckItems);
  grid.headerCt.on('columnhide',doCheckItems);
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fkj

But if you still want, you can bind to the `beforecheckchange` event on the `menucheckitems`:

```
var doCheckChange = function() {
    var showncolumns = Ext.Array.sum(grid.headerCt.query("gridcolumn").map(function(column) {return column.isVisible()?1:0;}));
    if(showncolumns >= 5) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Error','Too many columns checked');
        return false;
    }
};
Ext.each(grid.headerCt.getMenu().query("menucheckitem"),function(item) {
    item.on('beforecheckchange', doCheckChange);
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fkl

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply Alexander. 1st approach works perfectly, but I have to use 2nd . In 2nd approach I see that the checkboxes cannot be unchecked after max limit is reached.